# Custom Event Not Firing in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, custom-events, google-datalayer

I am trying to fire a custom event in Google Tag Manager for a Virtual Page View. I want to be able to track a conversion in a dynamic shopping cart page where the actual URL does not change.

I added the following code for a dataLayer and set it up to fire when the event= VirtualPageView but it's not working.

Any ideas?

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event':'VirtualPageView',
  'virtualPageURL':'/thankyou',
  'virtualPageTitle':'Thank You'
  'conversionValue':'value'
  'currencyCode':'currency'
});
```

[Google Tag Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEOk3.png)
[Custom Event Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xqrc.png)

Comment: What error messages are you seeing? How are you determining that it's not working?

Comment: When I debug with GTM, it states that it's not firing when I do a test conversion. There are other tags firing on the page (UA, Remarketing) but those fire sitewide.

Comment: Please include screenshots of your tag you're trying to fire, and the trigger  used to fire that tag. Also, please confirm, you said the dataLayer code you posted is set to fire when event = `VirtualPageView`?

Comment: Yes, when the event = "VirtualPageView".

Comment: Sorry, I mean, you said "added the following code for a dataLayer and set it up to fire when ....".  So what's set to fire when event = `VirtualPageView`? Also, please post screenshots.

Comment: The tag should fire in Google Tag Manager when the event =  VirtualPageView. I added screenshots to the original post. (sorry for my terminology, I am usually on the marketing side)

Comment: For one thing to fire a virtual page view, you should use the `page` field in your tag, not the `location` field. Also, for your "value", since you are already pushing `/thankyou` into the dataLayer, you can create a Data Layer type variable with the value set to `virtualPageURL`, and then just pass that into the value for the `page` field. I don't really see anything else wrong with the tags, so this may need more investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see a lot of missing commas after everything but the second line. This will cause the JS to fail which means no event is pushed into the dataLayer which means GTM won't see anything happening and therefore not fire any tags.

I.e. add a comma after `'virtualPageTitle':'Thank You` and after `'conversionValue':'value'`. Keep in mind that if you actually pass `'value'` as a string and an `AdWords Conversion Tag` looks for a float, it will fail that tag.

GTM is fairly finicky and will just stop execution when JS code related to it fails.